# Hebrew rendering in website

Tags: java, html, http, utf-8

I am working on a product which has an internet "Admin Panel" - Somewhere the user can see information about the product. One of the minimal requirements is that the website has both English and Hebrew Version. So what is the problem? The problem is that some of the characters look like [this](http://s4.postimg.org/t1yzko1lp/test3.png), But they should look like [this](http://s30.postimg.org/6j5dj0x8h/test2.png).

When I get a request from a browser I read an HTML file using this code (JAVA):

```
public static String loadPage(String page, String lang) {
    Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "htmlTemplate", lang, page + ".html");
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
        StringBuilder website = new StringBuilder();
        String currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            website.append(currentLine);
        }
        return website.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

(Thanks to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for helpig with reading it as UTF-8), After I read the file I am replacing some of the comments to with the correct data (For example: I have a comment like this: `<!--username-->` and I replace it with "Itay"), After the replacing I just send the response.

The server itself is hosted using sun's HttpServer.

I also made sure to do these things:

- I saved the html file as UTF-8
- In the html file there is this meta tag: `<meta charset="UTF-8">"`
- One of the response headers is: `Content-Type=text/html;charset=utf-8`

By the way i am using Chrome.

So I hope I gave enough details about my problem and if you need more feel free to tell me!

(I also hope I posted the question with the right tags and title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i found that i realy had a problem reading as UTF-8 but the other problem was thats I have not sent it back as UTF-8 So this is how i sent it:

```
public void end(HttpExchange t, String response, long tStart, int status) throws IOException {
        try {
            String temp = convertToUTF8(response);
            t.sendResponseHeaders(status, temp.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            OutputStream bout= new BufferedOutputStream(os);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(bout, "UTF-8");
            out.write(response);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("This VM does not support the UTF-8 character set.");
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        long tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long tDelta = tEnd - tStart;
        System.out.println("Done handling request! Time took: " + tDelta);
    }
```

Again thank you Jon Skeet for yor answer it was very helpfull!

```
Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "htmlTemplate", lang, page + ".html");
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
    StringBuilder website = new StringBuilder();
    String currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        website.append(currentLine);
    }
    return website.toString();
}
```

(This is how to read the file as UTF-8 using his way)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, don't use `FileReader`. It *always* uses the platform-default encoding, which may well not be appropriate for this file.

If you're using a modern version of Java, it's better to use:

```
Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "htmlTemplate", lang, page + ".html");
br = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
```

That will read in UTF-8 by default - if you wanted a different charset, you can specify it as another argument to `newBufferedReader`.

I'd also advise you to use a try-with-resources statement to get rid of all the cruft with a manual `finally` block:

```
Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "htmlTemplate", lang, page + ".html");
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
    StringBuilder website = new StringBuilder();
    String currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        website.append(currentLine);
    }
    return website.toString();
}
```

That will remove all line breaks, mind you. (Note that I've used `StringBuilder` to avoid performance issues from repeated string concatenation...)

Comment: Yes, Just looked up and saw it is using the default encoding, will try your solution and see if it will work!

Comment: I tried what you said but now there is a difrent problem [link](http://s4.postimg.org/t1yzko1lp/test3.png) .... (By difrent i mean i have the same problem but with difrent result)

Comment: @Itay: Well if that's a different problem, you should try to diagnose it, and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your `FileReader` to read as UTF8.